# Gradle Wrapper compile and build code and run a single unit test

Tags: bash, gradle, gradlew

Hey guys I am having a little trouble with the gradle wrapper.
Is there any good way to compile all my code, compile all my tests, and run a single test.
This is for a scripting command in a Jenkins pipeline.

I have used

- ./gradlew build, which runs all the tests
- ./gradlew build -x test, which compiles all main code and not allow me to run any tests

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the gradle documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering

```
# Executes all tests in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass

# Executes a single specified test in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.someSpecificMethod

gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.*someMethod*

# specific class
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTestClass

# specific class and method
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTestClass.someSpecificMethod
```